# Python system input accept only one character?

Tags: python, input, sys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python read a single character from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user)

I would like to create a line of code that accepts only a single character as it's input. For example...

```
var = my_input("Type a letter: ")

print var
```

on running, the moment you pressed a character-producing key, that character would be printed. How would I, then, create the function `my_input`?

Comment: I remember seeing something here, but it was different in linux and windows.

Comment: This thread deals with your exact question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user

Comment: Thanks! For some reason, it didn't come up as a duplicate as I was making it, and I did make sure to check. The third answer worked perfectly.